# Image is not displayed using html tag

Tags: html, image, browser, bootstrap-4

I am using the following code to display the image on my website:

```
   <img src="/logo.jpg"  alt="Image1">
```

The image is on my hard drive. However, the image is not displayed.

I have searched all over the internet and check the folder and path to be correct. The image is in the same folder as my HTML file.

I tried to upload the image in google drive and google photos and provide the HTML link however still I could not be able to display the image in both Chrome and IE.
Can anyone explain what can be the solution?

Comment: I have searched the questions all over the internet and none of them worked for me. Otherwise I would not post it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your image stored in the OS root directory?

If it's in the same folder as the html file then you want to remove the / at the beginning (or change it to ./)

/[filename] means file at the root of the OS/server (analogous to C:/ in Windows)
./[filename] means file in the current working directory (as does just [filename])
../[filename] means file in the parent directory